# How can I add Apple's source code for UITableViewCell to my project?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

**Before you tell me that all I need to do is import UIKit, I know all about importing, and NO, that's not what I need to do in this case.  Intrigued?  Confused?  Read on...**

I have two different, but similar, custom `UITableViewCell`s.  Both have a `UILabel` and a `UISwitch`.  Version one, `DisplayCell`, has a second `UILabel`, while version two, `EditCell`, has a `UIPickerView`.  How I use them is like this, in a static `UITableView` that I'm using as a fill-in-the-data form, `DisplayCell` is the standard view which displays the selected value. The user can tap on `DisplayCell` to replace it with `EditCell`, then use the `UIPickerView` to pick a new value and hit done (button in the nav bar at the top). `DisplayCell` is then brought back, displaying the newly selected value.  In either version the user can tap the switch to toggle whether or not the value from the `UIPickerView` should be used elsewhere in the form.

When it came time to write the code for the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> (UITableViewCell)` function I decided to rewrite my code so that I have a single class, `SwitchCell` that inherits from `UITableViewCell` and contains the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` for the switch, then have `DisplayCell` and `EditCell` inherit from `SwitchCell`.

This works fine, however `DisplayCell` is now nothing more than a `IBOutlet` for a `UILabel`, and `UITableViewCell`, which `DisplayCell` inherits from via `SwitchCell` already has two `UILabel` `IBOutlet`s, `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`.  The whole purpose in creating `SwitchCell` was to try and minimize code by only ever write any block of code once, something that I'm a bit of a fanatic about.  Thus I would very much rather have the `UILabel` in `DisplayCell` use the `detailTextLabel` `IBOutlet` from `UITabelViewCell`, rather than having to create a 'redundant' `UILabel` `IBOutlet` for it.

In order to link to an `IBOutlet` in a superclass you must be able to bring up the code for that superclass in the assistant editor.  Then you can just control+drag and link like normal.  Which means, in theory, I believe it should be possible to link my `UILabel` to `UITableViewCell`'s `detailTextLabel`, if I can access the appropriate line from the source code for `UITableViewCell` in the assistant editor.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Oh, and I'm working exclusively in Swift in this project, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: It's really not anymore efficient to use UITableViewCell's default UILabels than it is to just add your own.

> In order to link to an IBOutlet in a superclass you must be able to bring up the code for that superclass in the assistant editor.

Well, that's not correct. The assistant editor is not required to link to an IBOutlet defined in a superclass. But that's not important here anyway.

You can't link to detailTextLabel in Interface Builder because it's not defined with the @IBOutlet attribute. And although it is possible to override properties in Swift (so you can add @IBOutlet to it), that won't work in this case because an IBOutlet has to be mutable, and the superclass has defined the variable as immutable.

Now you could overcome this by adding your own setter method in the subclass to make the property mutable. I was able to do this with the following code:

```
var _detailTextLabel: UILabel?
@IBOutlet override var detailTextLabel: UILabel? {
    get {
        return super.detailTextLabel
    }
    set {
        _detailTextLabel = newValue
    }
}
```

I could wire this up in Interface Builder just fine. So perhaps I could tweak this code to actually get an set what I want (I don't think it would work as shown here). We're so far outside the realm of common-sense coding that we just need to stop and give up on this idea.

> Thus I would very much rather have the UILabel in DisplayCell use the detailTextLabel IBOutlet from UITabelViewCell, rather than having to create a 'redundant' UILabel IBOutlet for it.

I can relate. I'm just as anal.  :-)

However, if you do a little testing (or read the UITableViewCell header file) you'll see that UITableView is smart enough (optimized enough?) to not actually add a UILabel to the content view unless you try to use it. So at worst you have an unused property.

So it's really not inefficient to just add your own UILabel and property.